# Which magic stage is Mereoleona Vermillion?

Tags: black-clover

In Black Clover, supposedly magic knights are ranked from stage zero to stage nine, and those who has unconventional magic are considered Arcane Stage.

How about Mereoleona Vermillion? Is it ever mentioned which magic stage is she?

Comment: The clover kingdom does not use the stage ranking system. However, considering that Noelle in her valkyrie form was ranked at stage#1. I'd estimate that Mereoleona is stage 0 if not, at least 1. Cause we can say for sure that she's way stronger than Noelle.

Comment: My guess would be stage zero based on her relative power to those that have declared stages, but it hasn't been mentioned in the manga yet from what I can find (and as an avid reader). I'll post an answer if they ever mention it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not mentioned in the manga but she must be at stage zero , If Noel at stage one   so the lioness Mereoleona must be at stage zero